# add button to vaadin jpacontainer table

Tags: vaadin

I need to add buttons for every row of my table. The table's container data source is JPAContainer. How to do that? I have succesfully add buttons for table which data source is not a JPAContainer. This is what I do:

```
testable.addContainerProperty("button", Button.class, null);
Button btt = new Button("test");
Item newrow = testable.addItem("first");
newrow.getItemProperty("button").setValue(btt);
```

But if I declare the testable data source : testable.setContainerDataSource(jpa_test);
It does'nt work. Can someone help me please

Comment: did you try using addGeneratedColumn?

Answer (score -1):

First, create example class:

```
public class ExampleBean {
    private Integer id;
    private Button button;

    public ExampleBean() {
        button = new Button("Test") {
            {
                addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        // code here
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setButton(Button button) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Button getButton() {
        return button;
    }

    // ToString, Equals and/or HashCode methods if necessary
}
```

Second, create container:

```
private BeanItemContainer<ExampleBean> exampleBeanItemContainer = new BeanItemContainer<ExampleBean>(ExampleBean.class);
```

Next, fill container (add bean/beans to container) and assign container with table:

```
exampleBeanItemContainer.addBean(new ExampleBean() {
    {
        setId(1);
    }
});

table.setContainerDataSource(exampleBeanItemContainer);
```

Finally, set table headers and table headers visibility:

```
table.setVisibleColumns(new Object[] { "id", "button" });
table.setColumnHeaders(new String[] { "ID", "Button" });
```

Comment: The JPAContainer is a entierly different beast than the BeanItemContainer